# Javascript get part of URL and redirect

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get part of the URL and redirect to that part.

What I mean is that a Script generates a Link that gets opened. This link would be https://mywebsite.com/?s=https://google.com.

I now want to take the https://google.com part of the URL and redirect to that after a 5 second Timer.

How would I do that?

I tried

```
<script>
const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
console.log(parsedUrl.searchParams.get("s")); 
</script>
```

Which logs the URL i need in the console but I don't know how to redirect to that URL now after a 5 second Timer

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @Dexygen Sorry man, think i searched for the wrong things and didn't fully understand that i could just reuse parsedUrl.searchParams.get("s") in my redirect

Comment: Ok, just know that insufficient research is a reason for down-voting.  Just frustrated that other users who should know better didn't vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question! You're probably looking for javascript's `setTimeout` and `window.redirect` functions. Here is an example of how you use both of them.

```js
const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);

setTimeout(()=>{
    window.redirect(parsedUrl.searchParams.get("s")); // window.redirect takes in a link and redirects a user.
}, 5 * 1000); // setTimeout takes a function and a time in milliseconds
```